# Stop codeigniter from redirection

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, authentication

Is it possible to make codeigniter not to redirect after a failed login attempt and show a message on the same login box.
My login box is a popup type, which appears after I have clicked on the login button and disappears after clicking on the background.

Controllers

```
public function login_validation() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|trim|callback_validate_credentials');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|md5');
        if($this->form_validation->run()){
 $data=array(
   'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
   'is_logged_in' => 1
 );
 $this->session->set_userdata($data);
 redirect('site/members');
}else {
  $this->main();
   }

 }
public function validate_credentials(){
$this->load->model('model_users');

if($this->model_users->can_log_in()){    
echo 'success';
} else {
echo 'failed';
}
}
```

I was trying to change elses with error messages but it still redirected to another page.

Html:

```
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
<input id="username" name="email" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Username">            
<input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password" placeholder="Password">             
<button name="login_submit" class="submitbutton" onclick="checkFormData()">Login</button>
</div>


<script>

function checkFormData(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/validate_credentials",
    data: {
        email: $("#email").val(),
        password: $("#password").val()
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if(response == 'success'){
           location.href = 'site/members';
        } else {
           $("#errors").show();
        }
    }
});
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the alert in the modal, you'll want to check the data with ajax (javascript or jquery). For example you'd have something like this:

```
function checkFormData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>your_controller/validate_credentials",
        data: {
            email: $("#email").val(),
            password: $("#password).val()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if(response == 'success'){
               location.href = <where you want to send them>;
            } else {
               $("#errors").show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And your HTML would look something like:

```
<div class="hide" id="errors">Incorrect username/password.</div>
<input type="email" id="email" />
<input type="password" id="password" />
```

The class="hide" is meant to be something CSS related where you would have something like "display: none;".
Then in your controller you'd check like this:

```
if($this->model_users->can_log_in()){    
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

The echoed response is what will be sent to your ajax success function.

Edit:

You need to not use the form submission for the above to work, because with that method we don't want to submit the form, we want to pass the data from it.

```
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
    <input id="username" name="email" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Username">            
    <input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password" placeholder="Password">             
    <button name="login_submit" class="submitbutton" onclick="checkFormData()">Login</button>
</div>
```

I've also changed the javascript function above to be viewed as a function.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i still cannot make it work. I'm pretty new at php,ajax so maybe i'm doing something from. But if i'm following your steps  after failed login attempt i still getting redirected to blank login_validation page.

Comment: Can you edit your main question to show your HTML to me? Do that and when I get a chance I'll show you how to get it working. 

You'll also need to use jQuery to get the code that I posted above to work. If it's easier, you could always just ditch the modal and use a basic login screen.

Comment: added html. And yes i tried use jquery but my validation seems to stopped worked.

Comment: I've edited my post as well. I hope I've explained things well. If you need anything else after this, by all means, ask!

Comment: Thank you again! But i think i'm missing something. I edited how my files looks now but it looks like that jquery doesnt even take that values at all. Also when you said that i dont need form submission did u meant that my html file has to be like that (which i just edited) or still have some forms from before (echo form_open('site/login_validation');
echo validation_errors();
echo form_close();).

Comment: Like how you have it. You don't *have* to do it like that, you could always uses jQuery's onSubmit for the form, but with this it makes sure that you're passing the data. Try grabbing the values with jquery before doing the ajax call (comment it out even) and try something like `console.log($("#username").val());` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
window.location.href = '/redirectpage'
```